# My main function is repeating in an infinite loop and I do not know why

Tags: python, function, class

I am running a program that plays rock, paper, scissors. I have executed the code multiple times and everytime I do, the input asking the user to pick 0,1,2 repeats more than one time. It is only supposed to be asked one time per game cycle. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening, and how to fix it?

```
import random

# Function: Display Menu
# Input: none
# Output: none
# displays the game rules to the user
def displayMenu():
    print("Welcome! Let's play rock, paper, scissors.")
    print("The rules of the game are:")
    print("\tRock smashes scissors")
    print("\tScissors cut paper")
    print("\tPaper covers rock")
    print("\tIf both the choices are the same, it's a tie")

# Function: Get Computer Choice
# Input: none
# Output: integer that is randomly chosen, a number between 0 to 2
def getComputerChoice():
    computerChoice = random.randrange(0,3)
    return computerChoice

# Function: Get Player Choice
# Input: none
# Output: integer that represents the choice
# Asks the user for their choice: 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 for scissors
def getPlayerChoice():
    playerChoice = int(input("Please choose (0) for rock, (1) for paper or (2) for scissors"))
    return playerChoice

# Function: Play Round
# Input: two integers--one representing the computer's choice and the other representing the player's choice
# Output: integer (-1 if computer wins, 1 if player wins, 0 if there is a tie)
# This method contains the game logic so it stimulates the game and determines a winner
def playRound(getcomputerChoice, getplayerChoice):
    if getplayerChoice == 0 and getcomputerChoice == 2:
        return 1
    elif getcomputerChoice == 0 and getplayerChoice == 2:
        return -1
    elif getplayerChoice == 2 and getcomputerChoice == 1:
        return 1
    elif getcomputerChoice == 2 and getplayerChoice == 1:
        return -1
    elif getplayerChoice == 1 and getcomputerChoice == 0:
        return 1
    elif getcomputerChoice == 1 and getplayerChoice == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

# Function: Continue Game
# Input: none
# Output: boolean
# Ask the user is they want to continue (Y/N), and then return True or False accordingly
def continueGame():
    playAgain = input("Do you want to continue playing? Enter (y) for yes or (n) for no.")
    if playAgain.lower() == "y":
        return True
    elif playAgain.lower() == "n":
        return False

# Function: main
# Input: none
# Output: none
def main():
    displayMenu()
    getPlayerChoice()
    if getPlayerChoice() == 0:
        choicePlayer = "rock"
    elif getPlayerChoice() == 1:
        choicePlayer = "paper"
    elif getPlayerChoice() == 2:
        choicePlayer = "scissors"
    getComputerChoice()
    if getComputerChoice() == 0:
        choiceComputer = "rock"
    elif getComputerChoice() == 1:
        choiceComputer = "paper"
    elif getComputerChoice() == 2:
        choiceComputer = "scissors"
    print("You chose", choicePlayer + ".")
    print("The computer chose", choiceComputer + ".")
    playRound(getComputerChoice(), getPlayerChoice())
    continueGame()
    while continueGame() == True:
        displayMenu()
        getPlayerChoice()
        getComputerChoice()
        playRound(getComputerChoice(), getPlayerChoice())
        continueGame()

    playerCounter = 0
    computerCounter = 0
    tieCounter = 0

    while playRound(getPlayerChoice(), getPlayerChoice()) == -1:
        computerCounter += 1
    while playRound(getPlayerChoice(), getPlayerChoice()) == 1:
        playerCounter += 1
    while playRound(getPlayerChoice(), getPlayerChoice()) == 0:
        tieCounter += 1

    print()
    print("You won", playerCounter, "game(s).")
    print("The computer won", computerCounter, "game(s).")
    print("You tied with the computer", tieCounter, "time(s).")
    print()
    print("Thanks for playing!")

# Call Main
main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because when you do:

```
    if getPlayerChoice() == 0:
    choicePlayer = "rock"
```

You are actually calling the method again.

You should do:

```
p_choice = getPlayerChoice()

if p_choice == 0:
...
```